# Charts in zend framework2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, charts, zend-framework2

I am working with zend framework 2 and i want to display charts in some views but it doesn't work!!
This is my Action:

```
public function statvehAction(){
        $data = [
        'labels' => ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        'data' => [18,99,30,81,28,55,30]
        ];
        json_encode($data);
        $viewModel = new ViewModel(array('data' => $data));
        return $viewModel;
    }
```

this is my view:

```
<script src="../../../../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../../../../chart.min.js"></script>
<script>
              (function($){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");


        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "VehiculesController.php",
          dataType: "json"
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            var d = {
                labels: $data.labels,

                datasets : [
                    {
                        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        data: data.data }] };

            var barChart = new Chart(ctx).Bar(d);


        });



    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

But when i want to diplay my chart i got a white page whith no error !!
Please can you help me to solve this problem.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have a lot to do with ZF2, but more with a front end issue. What does the rendered source look like? Does the route get matched and does your controller action get called? Make sure by for example printing something in your controller action and then calling die. If you're sure the action gets called go from there troubleshooting the problem.

Comment: Firstly thank you very much for your help :) Yes the route get matched and i print the data i sent in the controller with var_dump but no chart shown in my view :/

Comment: No problem. Can you check what the generated output is? Is it really empty or is there still markup? Is display_errors on? Might be caused by an error in the code somewhere that's being suppressed.

Comment: no error is shown only my data is shown due to var_dump():          string '{"labels":["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],"data":[18,99,30,81,28,55,30]}' (length=99)

Comment: when i inspect my page the canvas is shown but it is empty :/

Comment: My guess would be that it's the references to jquery and chart.min.js. You could use the basepath view helper to render the correct paths, i.e.: <script src="<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo $this->basePath(); ?>/chart.min.js"></script> or even simpler just <script src="/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/chart.min.js"></script> Note that the paths to the javascripts are URL references and not absolute filesystem paths.

Comment: i don't have problem in those paths because when i inspect the element in the console no error shown so it knows all the paths. and the canevas is drawn but empty :/

Comment: you should read more about ViewStratergy to return Json to browser, so your js chart can work: use Zend\View\Model\JsonModel;  return new JsonModel([
            'data'   => $data
        ]);

Comment: Chu Khanh Van is right. Looks like the chart component does an ajax request to retrieve the data. It expects a json response (dataType parameter) and not a fully rendered view.

Comment: Thank you :) i did what you have said but the same problem i got an object JsonModel in my view but nothing drawn :/

Comment: This is my data shown in the view due to var_dump():                                                                      object(Zend\View\Model\JsonModel)[340]
  protected 'captureTo' => null protected 'jsonpCallback' => null
  protected 'children' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected 'options' =>array (size=0) empty
  protected 'template' => string '' (length=0)
  protected 'variables' => array (size=1)'data' => array (size=2)
          'labels' =>array (size=7)
              ...
          'data' =>array (size=7)
              ...
  protected 'append' => boolean false

Comment: You should use a tool like Firebug to see if the chart script actually calls your controller action. Also make sure the data is returned in the correct format.

Comment: My data id returned ad Json with all information so my chart call the controller !!